# Getting "Insufficient Permission" error while storing data into GCS from docker container in kubernetes engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I have configured gcloud with the project, service account and other configurations. Enabled google api and runs the application on GKE clusters.

I am getting the following error logs,

```
Exception in thread "Thread-10" com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Insufficient Permission
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:227)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:308)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$3.call(StorageImpl.java:203)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$3.call(StorageImpl.java:200)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.internalCreate(StorageImpl.java:199)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:161)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o?projection=full&uploadType=multipart
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:555)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:475)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:592)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:305)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Could you share more details on how you've configured RBAC for your **serviceaccount** you're using to access GCP API in your `Pod` ? Have you defined proper `Role` and `RoleBinding` ?

Comment: this is not an rbac related error. You just don't have access to GCS. May be scopes? Go to any node, and check if your nodes have GCS scope.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, have a look at this:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform

You need to create a Kubernetes (!) secret representing the GCP service account credentials.

You then volume-mount the secret into the containers that need to use the secret and  set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` referencing the account in the container's environment.

Answer (score 0):

> this is not an rbac related error. You just don't have access to GCS.
>   May be scopes? Go to any node, and check if your nodes have GCS scope.
>   – suren May 15 at 18:20

It looks like @suren is right and most probably it is the issue related to GCS scopes as the [403 error](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#403_Forbidden) can be related with authorization problems. You can check the scopes set for particular Compute Engine VM by running on it:

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/?recursive=true" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

It will retrieve this information from metadata server.
You will probably see only `storage-ro` scope when it comes to GCS as it is the default setting:

```
"scopes":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only"
```

and as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/instances/set-scopes), you will need to set:

```
storage-rw  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write
```

which on Compute Engine instances can be done as follows:

```
$ gcloud beta compute instances set-scopes example-instance \
      --scopes=storage-rw --zone=us-central1-b \
      --service-account=example-account
```

It requires however shutting down the instance to be able to apply changes to service-account. Otherwise you'll get the following error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.instances.set-scopes) Could not fetch resource:
 - The instance must be stopped before the service account can be changed.
```

But when using **GKE** you cannot simply stop individual worker node as it is part of a managed instance group.

However you can set scopes [when creating new GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create#--scopes) e.g. like this:

```
gcloud container clusters create test --scopes=storage-rw --service-account default --zone europe-west3-c
```